# ES6 class inheritance does not inherit

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I'm working my way through a ES6 video tutorial and recreating the use cases to better understand the syntax.

I'm on the subject of class inheritance. I have created a super class Person which is extended by Employee, and I also have a class Intern which extends Employee. I have a function called '`doWork()`' in Person class which return 'paid', in the Intern class I'm attempting to override in 'doWork' by having it return 'free'.

I assigned connor as a new Employee and beth as a new Intern. The issue is after I invoke a call to doWork() I'm only seeing 'Intern Free' in the console.log which is from the beth.doWork(). Shouldn't connor.doWork() return 'Employee Paid' since Employee is extending the class Person?

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
    set name(newValue) {
        if(newValue) {
            this._name = newValue;
        }
    }
    doWork() {
        return 'Paid Employee';
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    constructor(title, name) {
        super(name);
        this._title = title;
    }
    get title() {
        return this._title;
    }
}

class Intern extends Employee {
    doWork() {
        return 'Intern Free'
    }
}

let makeEveryoneWork = function(...people) {
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        results.push(people[i].doWork());
    }
    return results
}

let connor = new Employee("Doctor", "Connor");
let beth = new Intern("Student", "Beth");

connor.doWork();  //expecting to be 'Employee Paid'
beth.doWork();  // exprecting to be 'Intern Free'
```

Comment: Because you don't actually `console.log` the result of the method call? You just will see "Intern Free" on the console when `beth.doWork()` is the last statement in the snippet you pasted to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
    set name(newValue) {
        if(newValue) {
            this._name = newValue;
        }
    }
    doWork() {
        return 'Paid Employee';
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    constructor(title, name) {
        super(name);
        this._title = title;
    }
    get title() {
        return this._title;
    }
}

class Intern extends Employee {
    doWork() {
        return 'Intern Free'
    }
}

let makeEveryoneWork = function(...people) {
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        results.push(people[i].doWork());
    }
    return results
}

let connor = new Employee("Doctor", "Connor");
let beth = new Intern("Student", "Beth");

console.log(connor.doWork())  //expecting to be 'Employee Paid'
console.log(beth.doWork())  // exprecting to be 'Intern Free'
```

Works alright for me. Run the snippet. I just copy pasted your code with one minor change. i wrapped the last two lines in console.log calls.

Comment: That's not exactly the same code. What did you change?

Comment: i wrapped the last two lines in console.log calls

Comment: Wow! I can't believe i didn't notice that... thanks its been a long day. :)